# find function in linked list in c programming

Tags: c, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wanna write a program about linked list that gets a number and if the number was equal to the one of the nodes' data , gives the number of that node .
like the datas in 3 nodes are

```
123
56
78
```

and it gets a number like 56 and its equal to the second node's data so the output should be 2.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int data;

    node *next;

};

node* cnode();

void find(node *first,int i,int d);

int main()
{

    node *first,*last;

    int n,i,x,d;

    printf(" How many nodes ?\t");

    scanf("%d",&x);

    for(i=1;i<=x;i++){

        last=cnode();

        last->next=first;

        first=last;

    }

    printf("\n enter a particular data:\t");

    scanf("%d",&d);

    printf("\n number of the particular node:\t");

    find(first,i,d);

}

void find(node *first,int i,int d){

    int count=0;

    while (first != NULL)

    {

        if (first->data == d)

           count++;

        first = first->next;

    }

    if(count != 0){

        printf("%d",count);

    }

    if(count == 0){

        printf("\n NOT FOUND ! ");

    }


}
```

Comment: PLEASE! format your code properly

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: When asking a question, please actually ask a question.

Comment: Unrelated, but why did you put a en blank line between _all_ lines of your program?

Comment: On this line  `last->next = first;` `first` has not yet been initialized. There are most likely more problems though.

Comment: BTW, you forgot to show us `the `cnode()` function.

Comment: @Michael Walz In general the more blank lines in code the higher qualification of the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly this declaration of the structure

```
struct node{

    int data;

    node *next;

};
```

is not a valid C declaration.

You should write

```
struct node{

    int data;

    struct node *next;

};

typedef struct node node;
```

or

```
typedef struct node{

    int data;

    struct node *next;

} node;
```

You have to initialize at least node `first` with `NULL`. Otherwise the program will have undefined behavior.

```
node *first = NULL,*last;
```

The parameter `i` is not used within the function `find`. So it may be removed.

```
void find(node *first, int d);
```

The function definition can look at least like

```
void find( node *first, int d )
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( first != NULL && first->data != d )
    {
        first = first->next;
        ++count;
    }

    if ( first != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d",count);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n NOT FOUND ! ");
    }
}
```